# extract one element/data frame from a list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list of lists called cj1. Each list contains multiple data frames/elements. I want to extract the first element/data frame from each list in a separate list of data frames. The first rows in the first element of each list look like this

```
as.data.frame(cj1[[1]]) 
                    cj1[[1]]
..a15.pdf         1.27679608
..a17.pdf         1.05090176
..a18.pdf         1.51820192
```

..a15.pdf etc. is a rowname. If I use `as.data.frame(cj1[1][1])`, I get the same results, but the name of the column is the combination of all rownames and coeffients.
I'd like to make a list of all of these data frames. In the image below, the name of the element/data frame I am interested in is coefficients. In total there are 462 of them
[image]

To extract my desired list (results1) I tried:

```
results1<-sapply(cj1, function(x) as.data.frame(cj1[1][1]))
```

This renders a list with more than 15000 elements (same number as cj1), which is more than I would expect (462). In addition, when I access the elements, they are all the same: the coefficients data frame from list 1.

I also tried a for loop, which does not seem right to me, and not surprisingly does not work.

```
results1 <- c()
for (i in 1:462) {
  results1[[i]] <- as.data.frame(cj1[[1]])
}
```

My original list:

```
str(cj1)
List of 15708
 $ : Named num [1:22] 1.28 1.05 1.52 2.3 1.49 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:22] "..a15.pdf" "..a17.pdf" "..a18.pdf" "..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : Named num [1:92] -1.1 3.79 1.17 -1.12 -1.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:92] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:92] 0.0909 0.2637 0.269 0.1049 0.095 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:92] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:92] -0.327 -0.372 -1.394 -0.514 -1.373 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:92] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : num [1:22, 1:22] -1.45 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : int 22
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:92, 1:22] -1.45 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:92] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
  ..$ rank : int 22
  ..$ qraux: num [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ pivot: int [1:22] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ tol  : num 1e-11
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ :List of 12
  ..$ family    : chr "binomial"
  ..$ link      : chr "logit"
  ..$ linkfun   :function (mu)  
  ..$ linkinv   :function (eta)  
  ..$ variance  :function (mu)  
  ..$ dev.resids:function (y, mu, wt)  
  ..$ aic       :function (y, n, mu, wt, dev)  
  ..$ mu.eta    :function (eta)  
  ..$ initialize: language {     if (NCOL(y) == 1) { ...
  ..$ validmu   :function (mu)  
  ..$ valideta  :function (eta)  
  ..$ simulate  :function (object, nsim)  
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "family"
 $ : Named num [1:92] -2.3 -1.03 -1 -2.14 -2.25 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:92] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : num 87
 $ : num 148
 $ : num 148
 $ : int 17
 $ : Named num [1:92] 0.0826 0.1941 0.3933 0.1878 0.0859 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:92] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:92] 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:92] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : int 70
 $ : int 92
 $ : Named num [1:92] 0 1 0.5 0 0 0 0.5 1 0.5 0.5 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:92] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : logi TRUE
 $ : logi FALSE
 $ :'data.frame':   92 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Y: num [1:92, 1:2] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "win1" "win2"
  ..$ X: num [1:92, 1:22] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:92] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "..a15.pdf" "..a17.pdf" "..a18.pdf" "..a21.pdf" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Y ~ X - 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Y, X)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "X"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "X"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 0
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b58a90fc78> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Y, X)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "nmatrix.2" "nmatrix.22"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
 $ : language BTm(outcome = cbind(win1, win2), player1 = player1, player2 = player2,      data = x)
 $ :Class 'formula'  language ~..
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b58a910420> 
 $ :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Y ~ X - 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Y, X)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "X"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "X"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b58a90fc78> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Y, X)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "nmatrix.2" "nmatrix.22"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
 $ :'data.frame':   92 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ player1: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ player2: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 5 8 9 12 13 15 16 19 20 3 ...
  ..$ win1   : num [1:92] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ win2   : num [1:92] 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ : NULL
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ epsilon: num 1e-08
  ..$ maxit  : num 25
  ..$ trace  : logi FALSE
 $ : chr "glm.fit"
 $ : Named list()
 $ : int [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : chr ".."
 $ :'data.frame':   92 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ ..: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   92 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ ..: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 5 8 9 12 13 15 16 19 20 3 ...
 $ : chr ".."
 $ : Named num [1:22] 2.097 2.198 1.918 0.801 2.162 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:22] "..a15.pdf" "..a17.pdf" "..a18.pdf" "..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : Named num [1:94] -1.15 0.89 3.59 -1.14 -1.05 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:94] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:94] 0.1281 0.3097 0.2786 0.1266 0.0516 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:94] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:94] -0.522 -0.6154 -0.9306 0.0702 -1.3505 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:94] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : num [1:22, 1:22] -1.46 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : int 22
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:94, 1:22] -1.46 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:94] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
  ..$ rank : int 22
  ..$ qraux: num [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ pivot: int [1:22] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ tol  : num 1e-11
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ :List of 12
  ..$ family    : chr "binomial"
  ..$ link      : chr "logit"
  ..$ linkfun   :function (mu)  
  ..$ linkinv   :function (eta)  
  ..$ variance  :function (mu)  
  ..$ dev.resids:function (y, mu, wt)  
  ..$ aic       :function (y, n, mu, wt, dev)  
  ..$ mu.eta    :function (eta)  
  ..$ initialize: language {     if (NCOL(y) == 1) { ...
  ..$ validmu   :function (mu)  
  ..$ valideta  :function (eta)  
  ..$ simulate  :function (object, nsim)  
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "family"
 $ : Named num [1:94] -1.918 -0.801 -0.951 -1.931 -2.911 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:94] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : num 68
 $ : num 131
 $ : num 142
 $ : int 18
 $ : Named num [1:94] 0.1117 0.4276 0.201 0.1106 0.0979 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:94] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:94] 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:94] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : int 72
 $ : int 94
 $ : Named num [1:94] 0 0.5 1 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:94] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : logi TRUE
 $ : logi FALSE
 $ :'data.frame':   94 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Y: num [1:94, 1:2] 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "win1" "win2"
  ..$ X: num [1:94, 1:22] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:94] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "..a15.pdf" "..a17.pdf" "..a18.pdf" "..a21.pdf" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Y ~ X - 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Y, X)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "X"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "X"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 0
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b592c99120> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Y, X)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "nmatrix.2" "nmatrix.22"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
 $ : language BTm(outcome = cbind(win1, win2), player1 = player1, player2 = player2,      data = x)
 $ :Class 'formula'  language ~..
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b5877fb898> 
 $ :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Y ~ X - 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Y, X)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "X"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "X"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b592c99120> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Y, X)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "nmatrix.2" "nmatrix.22"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
 $ :'data.frame':   94 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ player1: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ player2: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 4 5 8 9 12 13 15 16 20 3 ...
  ..$ win1   : num [1:94] 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 ...
  ..$ win2   : num [1:94] 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : NULL
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ epsilon: num 1e-08
  ..$ maxit  : num 25
  ..$ trace  : logi FALSE
 $ : chr "glm.fit"
 $ : Named list()
 $ : int [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : chr ".."
 $ :'data.frame':   94 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ ..: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   94 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ ..: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 4 5 8 9 12 13 15 16 20 3 ...
 $ : chr ".."
 $ : Named num [1:22] 1.9 1.85 1.56 1.69 1.09 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:22] "..a15.pdf" "..a17.pdf" "..a18.pdf" "..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : Named num [1:89] -1.19 3.77 -1.26 6.01 -1.14 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:89] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:89] 0.156 0.265 0.205 0.166 0.124 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:89] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:89] -0.82 -0.743 -0.889 -0.789 -0.878 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:89] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : num [1:22, 1:22] -1.55 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
 $ : int 22
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:89, 1:22] -1.55 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:89] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "X..a15.pdf" "X..a17.pdf" "X..a18.pdf" "X..a21.pdf" ...
  ..$ rank : int 22
  ..$ qraux: num [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ pivot: int [1:22] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ tol  : num 1e-11
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ :List of 12
  ..$ family    : chr "binomial"
  ..$ link      : chr "logit"
  ..$ linkfun   :function (mu)  
  ..$ linkinv   :function (eta)  
  ..$ variance  :function (mu)  
  ..$ dev.resids:function (y, mu, wt)  
  ..$ aic       :function (y, n, mu, wt, dev)  
  ..$ mu.eta    :function (eta)  
  ..$ initialize: language {     if (NCOL(y) == 1) { ...
  ..$ validmu   :function (mu)  
  ..$ valideta  :function (eta)  
  ..$ simulate  :function (object, nsim)  
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "family"
 $ : Named num [1:89] -1.69 -1.02 -1.35 -1.61 -1.95 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:89] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : num 75.4
 $ : num 139
 $ : num 141
 $ : int 18
 $ : Named num [1:89] 0.132 0.195 0.163 0.139 0.218 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:89] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : Named num [1:89] 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 3 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:89] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : int 67
 $ : int 89
 $ : Named num [1:89] 0 1 0 1 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:89] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ : logi TRUE
 $ : logi FALSE
 $ :'data.frame':   89 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Y: num [1:89, 1:2] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "win1" "win2"
  ..$ X: num [1:89, 1:22] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:89] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "..a15.pdf" "..a17.pdf" "..a18.pdf" "..a21.pdf" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Y ~ X - 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Y, X)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "X"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "X"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 0
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b587c20440> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Y, X)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "nmatrix.2" "nmatrix.22"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
 $ : language BTm(outcome = cbind(win1, win2), player1 = player1, player2 = player2,      data = x)
 $ :Class 'formula'  language ~..
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b587c20b40> 
 $ :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Y ~ X - 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Y, X)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "X"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "X"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000001b587c20440> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Y, X)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "nmatrix.2" "nmatrix.22"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Y" "X"
 $ :'data.frame':   89 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ player1: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ player2: Factor w/ 23 levels "a12TTT.pdf","a15.pdf",..: 5 8 9 10 12 13 15 16 20 3 ...
  ..$ win1   : num [1:89] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ win2   : num [1:89] 1 0 1 0 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ : NULL
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ epsilon: num 1e-08
  ..$ maxit  : num 25
  ..$ trace  : logi FALSE
 $ : chr "glm.fit"
 $ : Named list()
 $ : int [1:22] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : chr ".."
  [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 34 462
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:34] "coefficients" "residuals" "fitted.values" "effects" ...
  ..$ : NULL
```

Extract from dput

```
dput(cj1[c(1, 3, 8)])
list(c(..a15.pdf = 1.27679607834331, ..a17.pdf = 1.05090175857491, 
..a18.pdf = 1.51820192474905, ..a21.pdf = 2.30296037386815, ..a2TTT.pdf = 1.48568731934637, 
..a5.pdf = 0.493713103224402, ..B11.pdf = 1.02705905465749, ..B12.pdf = 0.999747360884078, 
..B13.pdf = 2.40828101927852, ..B22.pdf = 0.695152132033603, 
..B24.pdf = 2.1436001615064, ..B4.pdf = 2.25444037842867, ..B7.pdf = 0.909773940025014, 
..B8.pdf = 1.14837173756827, `..cw10-1.pdf` = -1.36323271003293, 
`..cw15-1TTT.pdf` = 0.341428535787024, `..cw17-1.pdf` = -0.786878348480425, 
..cw18.pdf = 0.793720472787986, ..cw3.pdf = -1.57831038567642, 
..cw4.pdf = 0.277733503122777, ..cw7_1TTT.pdf = -0.0364645818969112, 
`..cw13-1.pdf` = -18.336668416705), c(`1` = 0.0908780807219899, 
`2` = 0.263654664895121, `3` = 0.268991096134461, `4` = 0.104930779989728, 
`5` = 0.0949671345831925, `6` = 0.240786617491842, `7` = 0.796284595482489, 
`8` = 0.31137037055408, `9` = 0.82896509427021, `10` = 0.556234653434742, 
`11` = 0.447966262353147, `12` = 0.562111772393927, `13` = 0.64144559057026, 
`14` = 0.295919740681443, `15` = 0.590739226571063, `16` = 0.618473870745292, 
`17` = 0.730874229815385, `18` = 0.385255456804764, `19` = 0.392984164719899, 
`20` = 0.505960393621032, `21` = 0.512785811414426, `22` = 0.588011150512112, 
`23` = 0.230846313945379, `24` = 0.917898796713428, `25` = 0.670284750854893, 
`26` = 0.862685953007114, `27` = 0.99999999619736, `28` = 0.508127935292484, 
`29` = 0.735846044750689, `30` = 0.620375626350015, `31` = 0.348554704521668, 
`32` = 0.946921016898213, `33` = 0.909296911948067, `34` = 0.673593098928319, 
`35` = 0.825586698787513, `36` = 0.78637523124224, `37` = 0.473694150487632, 
`38` = 0.883420398016852, `39` = 0.999999998912766, `40` = 0.729477690591574, 
`41` = 0.612688711990574, `42` = 0.341208618334042, `43` = 0.945262830874797, 
`44` = 0.758460698474656, `45` = 0.769936700176506, `46` = 0.820855140443936, 
`47` = 0.146699277115816, `48` = 0.397459740469979, `49` = 0.537997737731323, 
`50` = 0.782550437769477, `51` = 0.888154125425794, `52` = 0.553785981995655, 
`53` = 0.582223288022616, `54` = 0.226640083932377, `55` = 0.529287713363298, 
`56` = 0.999999996105605, `57` = 0.196465439953117, `58` = 0.551325299580471, 
`59` = 0.92943599314157, `60` = 0.738118436855869, `61` = 0.893836974671663, 
`62` = 0.920176356697468, `63` = 0.99999999902145, `64` = 0.173748802751829, 
`65` = 0.446549562485168, `66` = 0.388595549230014, `67` = 0.587520249127046, 
`68` = 0.814879076916803, `69` = 0.4753778467418, `70` = 0.90665523878871, 
`71` = 0.999999994572681, `72` = 0.730119396156374, `73` = 0.970881561088295, 
`74` = 0.865979290569218, `75` = 0.898444979546349, `76` = 0.793256288161879, 
`77` = 0.871357134749265, `78` = 0.811642757783275, `79` = 0.440631930364752, 
`80` = 0.906616650865072, `81` = 0.845096998613173, `82` = 0.691457736894216, 
`83` = 0.873829387141476, `84` = 0.587745042243573, `85` = 0.7658162723501, 
`86` = 0.999999996550512, `87` = 0.755526305253868, `88` = 0.515918376716212, 
`89` = 0.999999992269536, `90` = 0.999999976109623, `91` = 0.135164835661148, 
`92` = 0.999999947284594), structure(list(family = "binomial", 
    link = "logit", linkfun = function (mu) 
    .Call(C_logit_link, mu), linkinv = function (eta) 
    .Call(C_logit_linkinv, eta), variance = function (mu) 
    mu * (1 - mu), dev.resids = function (y, mu, wt) 
    .Call(C_binomial_dev_resids, y, mu, wt), aic = function (y, 
        n, mu, wt, dev) 
    {
        m <- if (any(n > 1)) 
            n
        else wt
        -2 * sum(ifelse(m > 0, (wt/m), 0) * dbinom(round(m * 
            y), round(m), mu, log = TRUE))
    }, mu.eta = function (eta) 
    .Call(C_logit_mu_eta, eta), initialize = {
        if (NCOL(y) == 1) {
            if (is.factor(y)) 
                y <- y != levels(y)[1L]
            n <- rep.int(1, nobs)
            y[weights == 0] <- 0
            if (any(y < 0 | y > 1)) 
                stop("y values must be 0 <= y <= 1")
            mustart <- (weights * y + 0.5)/(weights + 1)
            m <- weights * y
            if ("binomial" == "binomial" && any(abs(m - round(m)) > 
                0.001)) 
                warning(gettextf("non-integer #successes in a %s glm!", 
                  "binomial"), domain = NA)
        }
        else if (NCOL(y) == 2) {
            if ("binomial" == "binomial" && any(abs(y - round(y)) > 
                0.001)) 
                warning(gettextf("non-integer counts in a %s glm!", 
                  "binomial"), domain = NA)
            n <- (y1 <- y[, 1L]) + y[, 2L]
            y <- y1/n
            if (any(n0 <- n == 0)) 
                y[n0] <- 0
            weights <- weights * n
            mustart <- (n * y + 0.5)/(n + 1)
        }
        else stop(gettextf("for the '%s' family, y must be a vector of 0 and 1's\nor a 2 column matrix where col 1 is no. successes and col 2 is no. failures", 
            "binomial"), domain = NA)
    }, validmu = function (mu) 
    all(is.finite(mu)) && all(mu > 0 & mu < 1), valideta = function (eta) 
    TRUE, simulate = function (object, nsim) 
    {
        ftd <- fitted(object)
        n <- length(ftd)
        ntot <- n * nsim
        wts <- object$prior.weights
        if (any(wts%%1 != 0)) 
            stop("cannot simulate from non-integer prior.weights")
        if (!is.null(m <- object$model)) {
            y <- model.response(m)
            if (is.factor(y)) {
                yy <- factor(1 + rbinom(ntot, size = 1, prob = ftd), 
                  labels = levels(y))
                split(yy, rep(seq_len(nsim), each = n))
            }
            else if (is.matrix(y) && ncol(y) == 2) {
                yy <- vector("list", nsim)
                for (i in seq_len(nsim)) {
                  Y <- rbinom(n, size = wts, prob = ftd)
                  YY <- cbind(Y, wts - Y)
                  colnames(YY) <- colnames(y)
                  yy[[i]] <- YY
                }
                yy
            }
            else rbinom(ntot, size = wts, prob = ftd)/wts
        }
        else rbinom(ntot, size = wts, prob = ftd)/wts
    }), class = "family"))
```

> The dput output from above probably presents the rows 1,3,8 from V1 only i.e. coefficients, fitted values, family  (see image here).
> [image]

The desired output would be a list of data frames with the coefficients and their names (first row) in all of the columns presented in the image, i.e. V1:V462. When I extract the data from the first row and first column, the names are rownames. But I was not able to access coefficients in V2 etc. `cj2[2][1]` accessess the residuals (second row) in V1. `cj2[1][2]` gives null.
Illustration of the output

Data frame one

```
..a15.pdf         1.27679608
..a17.pdf         1.05090176
..a18.pdf         1.51820192 and so on for the 22 names that I have (i.e.a15.pdf)
```

Data frame 2

```
..a15.pdf         2.09668756
..a17.pdf         2.19826038.....etc for 22 names (if they are all included).
```

So basically I want the data that on the image appears to be in row one across all the columns.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We don't need your entire data set, just something to test with. Images of data aren't helpful because we can't copy/paste those into R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after messing around, the answer seems to be very simple: `results1<-cj1["coefficients",]. This creates the list that I want.  Akrun, if you read this, thank you for your support.